# Trying to download zipped blob but file is corrupted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to zip some files in my webapp and initiate a download. It is working quite fine for a single file using the ContentService. However when I try to download the zipped blob, the file is corrupted. Maybe I'm doing it wrong... my guess getDataAsString for zipped blob is a no go.

Anyone has any idea on how to do it?

This is what I tried so far.

```
function doGet(e)
{  
  var blobs = [];

  blobs.push(Utilities.newBlob( "Some text", "text/plain", "a.txt"));
  blobs.push(Utilities.newBlob( "Some more text", "text/plain", "b.txt"));
  blobs.push(Utilities.newBlob( "More Text", "text/plain", "c.txt"));

  var zippedBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs);  

  return ContentService.createTextOutput( zippedBlob.getDataAsString() ).downloadAsFile( "all.zip");
}
```

Comment: What was the result of your experiment so far?

Comment: Still corrupted. I tried creating a file in my drive with the zipped blob and it works. So I guess the blob is valid because I can click and download. Content can be extracted fine, etc.

`var zippedBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs, "all.zip"); 
var file = DriveApp.createFile(zippedBlob);`

However I can't trigger the download without corrupting the file.

Comment: So you generate a valid ZIP file on your server? What do you mean by "I can't trigger the download without corrupting the file"? When your file is downloaded it looks different?

Comment: I mean the zip file on my drive is fine. I can download and extract my 3 text files. However when i try to use the downloadAsFile method it is corrupted when i try to unzip.

Comment: so when you can download it and extract, where is the problem?

Comment: When I access my webapp url, it triggers the download thru the 'doGet' and 'downloadAsFile'. But the zip downloaded is corrupted.

Comment: have you analyzed the differences of the files downloaded via `downloadAsFile` and file on your file system?

Comment: Ah yes. We are getting somewhere. Very similar. When I diff both files some characters are not the same. Must be related to string encoding. I see getDataAsString can accept a charset. I'll experiment around that.
Seems the corrupt one is encoded in utf-8 when the valid one from google drive is ansi.